# Automatic release tag Github

Tags: git, git-commit

Is there a way to make release tag creation automatic in git?

When I commit a change in any of the files, it has to create a release tag with the updated version number? Is it a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

the best you can do (afaik) is to create a plugin/script that uses the API.

here's an example: https://github.com/jutzig/github-release-plugin